# 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.' while deleting?

Tags: c#, xaml, entity-framework-6, ado.net

I tried to make a remove method of an object on a table of my database for a WPF project using C#, EF6 and XAML. I tried several different variation of it my last one. The error that VS throw me is the following one:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'

Code:

```
private void btnSupprimer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var empASupprimer = ListViewEmployes.SelectedItems[0] as Employe;
    
    if (empASupprimer == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        using (var x = new ScriptBDEntity())
        {
            x.Employes.Attach(empASupprimer);
            x.Employes.Remove(empASupprimer);
                   
            x.SaveChanges();

            loadlistview();
            MessageBox.Show("Vous avez supprimer l'employé:" + empASupprimer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to get employe by Id instead use attach ?
Like

```
var employe = x.Employes.Single(e => e.Id == empASupprimer.Id),
X.Employes.Remove(employe);
X.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: my current solution is to detach from the main context and attach it to the "x" one is it a valid solution or do you think ive should be using only my main one ?

Comment: @JeremySimard You can simply use the non tracking entities to bind your list by calling `.AsNoTracking()` on the your bind query collection. This way you don't need to detach them.

Comment: @JeremySimard use the solution propose by vendettamit. In general for read prefer use AsNoTracking(), when you are not sure if entities will be updated. It's more performant.